# Has there ever been an instance of a starship needing to eject its nacelles in "Star Trek?"

Tags: star-trek

A little bit of background: I own a *Star Trek* trading card collection (1996 TOS I believe). On a card about the warp engines, it says that a *Constitution* class can eject those engines if they were too damaged or something. I know this is beta canon, but has it ever been utilized in books, games, or comics?

Comment: [Can Galaxy-class starships eject their warp nacelles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174835/can-galaxy-class-starships-eject-their-warp-nacelles) - Related not dupe

Comment: I don't know the status of the _Star Fleet Technical Manual_ (1975) vis-a-vis canon, but I believe that that document also specified that the warp nacelles could be detached/ejected at need.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I think it's generally considered canon, because material from it was incorporated into some of the films.

Comment: It happened involuntarily in *Star Trek: Beyond*, but I imagine that's not what you were thinking.  It is notable that they were still able to maneuver to a certain degree on impulse engines after losing the nacelles though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the novel [*Prime Directive*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Directive_(novel)):

> Not with the starboard warp-propulsion nacelle completely gone - the one that Spock *had managed to jettison in time*. Unlike the port nacelle.

Not a spoiler but an interesting part of a good novel.

Comment: Also Star Trek: Cast No Shadow,

Answer (score 26):

The Enterprise certainly *needed* to jettison its nacelles in [TOS: The Savage Curtain](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Savage_Curtain_(episode)) (and Kirk anticipates that they can do this), although the crew ultimately did not receive his order.

> **KIRK:** *Scotty, inform Starfleet Command. **Disengage nacelles, Jettison if possible.** Mister Spock, assist them. Advise and analyse. Scotty? Scotty?*
>
> **YARNEK:** *Your communicators no longer function, Captain. You may proceed with the spectacle.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: The Savage Curtain - Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/77.htm)</sup></sub>

A similar situation occurs in [TOS: The Apple](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Apple_(episode)). Kirk suggests they lose the nacelles *if needed*, but Scotty comes up with an ingenious fix and they end up not doing so.

> **KIRK:** *Then use your imagination. Tie every ounce of power the ship has into the impulse engines. **Discard the warp drive nacelles if you have to,** and crack out of there with the main section, but get that ship out of there!*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Sir, I'm going to switch over everything but the life-support systems and boost the impulse power, but that's just about as dangerous.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Do it. Kirk out.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: The Apple - Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/38.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: this is a better answer since it cites canon, not books (though, the question does ask about books)

Comment: Rock! Is not the Excalbian's name Yarnek?

Comment: @HamSandwich - You are, of course correct.

Comment: Of course this is the better answer. It references TOS, where it all started. I'm still hooked. This 25th century stuff will never hold up.

Comment: These may have been references to separating the primary hull, aka the "saucer section," from the secondary hull, the engineering section that had the nacelles attached, rather than detatching the nacelles from the pillars. Though I don't think the details of Constitution-class starships were all that well-defined even in TOS and varied among episodes.

Comment: @Jeffronicus - You're not wrong, but he does quite clearly say to eject the nacelles, not detach the saucer.

Answer (score 6):

Spock’s long-range shuttle in the first movie, the *Surak*, [detached its nacelles.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJmQGSMKyPU)

[image: Shuttlecraft separating]

**Edit:** If you strictly meant a large starship severing its nacelles in an emergency, the *Enterprise-D* did two things similar but not identical to that: detaching its saucer section (In “Encounter at Farpoint”, “Arsenal of Freedom”, “Best of Both Worlds” and one or two other times), and ejecting its warp core in “Generations.”

Comment: Really don't think this is the same thing.  This is a shuttle with warp kind of like what Obi-wan used to attach a hyperdrive to his ship in Attack of the Clones.  Detaching the nacelles of a starship is an emergency procedure to avoid a very big explosion and reflects that starships are modular to some degree.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I don't think it's really what OP was asking, but it does tangentially meet the wording of the question "*or something*"

Comment: @lucasbachmann I’ve added a paragraph to address that narrower question.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to hyperspace "sleds" used by many Clone Wars-era fighters in Star Wars. This is not a case of ejecting engines in an emergency, but designing modular systems for practical multi-use.

Comment: upvote for answering the letter if not the spirit of the question but mostly for a great image of the model of that craft

Answer (score 1):

Based entirely upon purely visual evidence from the show: While things happened too fast for the crew to react, it might have been a good idea to do so in [TNG:Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)).

There, the Bozeman collides with and rips open one of the warp nacelles, which apparently causes a cascading failure of various systems throughout the ship.

Soon after, the Enterprise is destroyed after what appears like one of the warp nacelles explodes.

Interestingly, the dialogue does not point to the possibility of ejecting a nacelle, but it seems like, when done right after (or even before) the collision, the Enterprise might have been saved that way.

Comment: This is not about *Constitution* class, and further references a "what if" from an episode of another series than TOS (where *Constitution* class ships mainly appeared).

Comment: @ZeissIkon: The question is not specific to Constitution class vessels. The title asks quite generally about "a starship". The question body only mentions the Constitution class as an example, without restricting the question to that. Also, the question is tagged [tag:star-trek], which indicates this is about the Star Trek universe/franchise as a whole, not just TOS. Therefore, the downvotes are unwarranted.

Comment: Still doesn't answer "has it ever been utilized" -- you speculate that it might have saved the *Enterprise D*, but don't provide an example of it being done.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Once again, I have to point you to the title, which asks whether there has been an instance of a starship *needing* to eject the nacelles. Likewise, "utilize" in the question body refers to the plot element that a starship *can* eject its nacelles, not that the protagonists necessarily went throught with the idea.

Comment: I feel the spirit of the question is more about whether the nacelles could be ejected, rather than whether they should have been, or whether they were actually ejected in a scene. This answer does indicate that such a question is relevant, but doesn't really get to the heart of the issue: are critically-failing warp nacelles like Chernobyl, where we have to deal with the issue where it sits, or is it like a grenade, where we have few moments after the pin is pulled to get rid of it and hide?